# Flutter Test Navigation from a method error

Tags: flutter, flutter-navigation

I am writing unit tests for a flutter app however I am encountering a problem when testing a method which has navigation inside it.
I am getting this errror `The argument type 'Null' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Route<dynamic>'.` from this section of the code `verify(mockObserver.didPush(any, any)).called(1);`. It occurs on the first any in `didPush(any, any)`.

This is the method in question,

```
  doLogout(BuildContext context) async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

    // Remove data for the following key.
    await prefs.remove('userData');
    await prefs.remove('userTokenData');
    await prefs.remove('invoice_list');
    await prefs.remove('expires_in');

    Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
      return SplashScreen(
        activeController: SignInController(),
      );
    }), (route) => false);
  }
```

This is the test I have written,

```
  testWidgets('Test doLogout method', (WidgetTester tester) async {
    SharedPreferences.setMockInitialValues({
      'userData': userData,
      'userTokenData': userTokenData,
      'invoice_list': invoice_list,
      'expires_in': expires_in
    }); // Set initial shared preferences values
    final mockObserver = MockNavigatorObserver();

    // Create a mock context
    final context = MockBuildContext();

    // Run the method
    await mainController.doLogoutTest(context);

    // Verify the shared preferences data is removed
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    expect(prefs.getString('userData'), null);
    expect(prefs.getString('userTokenData'), null);
    expect(prefs.getString('consignment_list'), null);
    expect(prefs.getString('invoice_list'), null);
    expect(prefs.getString('expires_in'), null);

    await tester.pumpWidget(
      MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
          body: Builder(
            builder: (context) => ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) => SplashScreen(
                      activeController: SignInController(),
                    ),
                  ),
                      (route) => false,
                );
              }, child: Text('Logout'),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        navigatorObservers: [mockObserver],
      ),
    );

    verify(mockObserver.didPush(any, any)).called(1);

    await tester.tap(find.byType(ElevatedButton));
    await tester.pumpAndSettle();

    verify(mockObserver.didPush(any, any)).called(1);
    expect(find.byType(SplashScreen), findsOneWidget);
  });
}
```

Id like to know how to fix it